# Deedle OptionalValue.Missing can't be dropped by Series.dropmissing

Tags: f#, deedle

this is the code example from http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/reference/deedle-seriesmodule.html

```
let s1 = series [ 1 => 1.0; 2 => Double.NaN ]
s1 |> Series.dropMissing
```

the Missing value will be dropped as expected. however if I change this to

```
let s2 = series [ 1 => OptionalValue(1.0); 2 => OptionalValue.Missing ]
s2 |> Series.dropMissing
```

the missing value won't be dropped.

I noticed S2 is a

```
Series<int,OptionalValue<float>>
```

type while s1 is

```
Series<int,float>
```

Is this behaviour by design?

The Reason I asked this question is I have this code from this answer [Deedle moving window stats calcuation with a dynamic condition and boundary.atending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25103662/deedle-moving-window-stats-calcuation-with-a-dynamic-condition-and-boundary-aten)

```
let lastKey = ref None
let r = 
  ts |> Series.aggregateInto
      (WindowWhile(fun d1 d2 -> d1.AddMonths(1) >= d2)) (fun seg -> seg.Data.LastKey())
      (fun ds -> 
         match lastKey.Value, ds.Data.LastKey() with 
         | Some lk, clk when lk = clk -> OptionalValue.Missing
         | _, clk -> lastKey := Some clk; OptionalValue(ds.Data))
     |> Series.dropMissing
```

The Series.aggregateInto somehow can return a non OptionalValue Series while still contain missing value. if I want to use OptionalValue.Missing in a series I create so they can be properly ignored by Stats.mean what is the right way to do it?

Also writing a Series/Frame to csv with missing value Deedle will put blank in the output. however if Series/Frame contains OptionalValue Deedle will put the string  in the output. is this by design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OptionalValue` type in Deedle is the internal representation of optional values inside a series. So, if you have `Series<Date, float>`, it will actually store data as `OptionalValue<float>`. We do not completely hide this from users - sometimes (like in the aggregation sample), Deedle will take `OptionalValue` and then use it directly in the internal representation to make things faster.

However, you probably never want to use `Series<K, OptionalValue<T>>`, because that is an odd kind of series (Deedle handles missing values automatically, so there is no need for this).

If you want to specify missing values when creating a series, you can use:

```
let s2 = Series.ofOptionalObservations [ 1 => Some(1.0); 2 => None ]
s2 |> Series.dropMissing
```

The F# API generally prefers standard F# `option` type, so this is what `ofOptionalObservations` takes. The `dropMissing` function works fine on series created in this way.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This makes sense now. I was trying to build on logic of aggregateinto to have another level of check on the DS and ignore any DS who has the required number of window size but not all of the items in the window contain values.